# Get-ChildItem -Recurse with File Shares

Tags: powershell, file-server

I want to list all file names on my file server. The `-Recurse` option works within a file share.

```
$shareName = "\\myFileServer\myShare01"
Get-ChildItem -Path $shareName -File -Recurse | Select FullName

FullName
--------
\\myFileServer\myShare01\test.txt
\\myFileServer\myShare01\testdir\anotherfile.txt
```

How can I `-Recurse` through all shares and files on `myFileServer` to output something like the following?

```
FullName
--------
\\myFileServer\myShare01\test.txt
\\myFileServer\myShare01\testdir\anotherfile.txt
\\myFileServer\myShare02\test2.txt
\\myFileServer\Testshare\test.txt
```

Comment: If you have a list of the shares you can use a loop

Comment: [1] you can get a list of shares with either `Get-SmbShare` or `Get-FileShare`. ///// [2] using `Get-ChildItem` for large dir trees can be S_L_O_W. [*grin*] instead use `robocopy` with the 'list only' parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Example powershell script using `net view` to list the shares:

```
$server = "myServer.domain.com"

# use NET VIEW to list visible shares and select only the names
$shares = net view "\\$server" /all | 
  select -Skip 7 | 
  Where {$_ -match 'disk*'} | 
  Foreach {$_ -match '^(.+?)\s+Disk*'|out-null;$matches[1]}

# list files in share
Foreach ($share in $shares) {
  Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$server\$share" -File -Recurse | Select FullName 
}
```